# Filtering by checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have suffering one issue in my rails application search by checkbox.

This is my checkbox code:

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get">
  <%= check_box_tag :title, params[:title] %> Title
  <input type="submit" value="Fielter" />
</form>
```

This code searching but showing default `=on` in url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?title=on
```

How can I search title like `ABC` & remove default `=on`.

I need like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/search?title=ABC
```

Thanks

Comment: from where the `default` value is coming ?

Comment: Try changing it to `<%= check_box_tag :title %> Title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})

I believe the default value is coming from the `params[:title]` which you have in the `check_box_tag`.

Because when you have `<%= check_box_tag :title, params[:title] %>`, the ***HTML*** equivalent will be

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="checkbox" value="on" /> #assumning the value of params[:title] is on
```

So the value of checkbox always will be **on**.

Try changing it to

```
<%= check_box_tag :title %> Title
```

Comment: Thanks @pavan, solve problem, but now create one issue, showing single checkbox result, I need showing result multi checkbox checked, how can is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That specific url pattern might be hard to do without javascript, but you can get the desired result (searching on the title only if the checkbox is checked) fairly easily by handling the logic server-side.

Just modify your form to always have the title as a hidden field (so it always gets passed as a parameter on submit) along with the checkbox, which will get passed as a parameter as either 1 or a 0 (true or false) depending on if it's checked or not. Then, you handle the logic in your search path: If the checkbox parameter is true, then search based on the title parameter. if the checkbox is false, then don't use the title parameter.

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get">
  <%= hidden_field_tag "title", :title %>
  <%= check_box_tag :use_title %> Title
  <input type="submit" value="Fielter" />
</form>
```

This will give you a url pattern that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?title="ABC"&use_title="1"
or
http://localhost:3000/search?title="ABC"&use_title="0"
```

And in the controller action:

```
if params[:use_title]
  do_something      # Use params[:title] in your search
else
  do_something_else # Don't use params[:title] in your search
end
```

That should give you the desired behavior.